# Image compression on uiwebview html form

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiimage

I have a simple html form, with an input of type image:

```
    ...
    <form action="new.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="text"><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    ...
```

In an iOS app I've implemented a `UIWebView`, this webview loads the html provided before.

In this form I can add a text and a file (an image in this case) but what I want to do is pre-process the image, if the image is to big then call a method that returns a smaller image.

I've tried to intercept the request with `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and modify the NSData from the request body/bodyStream but it seems too messy.

I've also tried using `javascript` to call native Objc methods using a custom `URI`:

```
function selectFile() { 
    window.location = "testapp://selectFile";
}
```

And the app part:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"testapp"]) {
        [self openCustomFile];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Using this I can call my own file chooser and do whatever I want to the `UIImage`, but my problem now is that I don't know how can I attach this to the form on the `UIWebView`, as far as I know, that is not possible.

So, is there any way to preprocess an image to be attached on a `UIWebView` form?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can render the image file to a canvas element and the convert the canvas to a resized/compressed image for the upload.
Something like this should work:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="file" id="imageFile"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('imageFile').addEventListener('change', resize);

    function resize(e) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 200;
        canvas.height = 200;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        img.onload = function() {
            //convert image to canvas
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5),
            blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL),
            fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
            fd.append("canvasImage", blob);
            //remove imageFile
            var imageFile = document.getElementById('imageFile');
            document.getElementById('form').removeChild(imageFile);
        }
    }
</script>
```